# SQL SERVER case when text contains two hyphens

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have encountered problem in writing case. If there is two hyphens in one text how can I write in sql server statement as a case expression?

the row value is as below:

1. PA-PB-PC (2 hyphens)
2. PA-PAC (1 hyphen)

the desired result will be something like this

```
Case when (section text contains two hyphens) then isnull(parsename(replace
 (ResponsibleSection,'-','.'),2)  else isnull(parsename(replace
 (ResponsibleSection,'-','.'),1)
```

This is my original problem code:-

```
select ResponsibleSection = isnull(parsename(replace
 (ResponsibleSection,'-','.'),2),Section) from FeedbackOwnerSetting
  Group by ResponsibleSection
```

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pattern matching:

```
CASE WHEN YourColumn LIKE '%-%-%' THEN [True Expression] ELSE [False Expression] END
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kit. You've let 3 people know that their input was right, so please make sure you mark the one you used as the solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

use to replace() to remove the '-' and find the difference in length

```
CASE len(col) - len(replace(col, '-', ''))
     WHEN 1 THEN '1 hyphens'
     WHEN 2 THEN '2 hyphens'
     END
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather then pattern matching already suggested, I would recommend just counting occurence of a hyphen"

```
CASE LEN(YourColumn) - LEN(REPLACE(YourColumn, '-', '')) WHEN 2 THEN [True Expression] ELSE [False Expression] END
```